# Convert NSDate to Date

Tags: swift, core-data, nsdate

this might be a stupid question, but I can´t find the information. I'm using CoreData in my app, and I save an array of structs. The problem is when I fetch and try to restore it into the struct array, I have a problem with my Date variable; I can't find a way to convert it from NSDate to Date, I try using `as Date`, but it makes me force downcast and I'm not sure if it's safe. Is it correct? or is there another way?

This is my Struc:

```
struct MyData {
        var value = Int()
        var date = Date()
        var take = Int()
        var commnt = String()
    }
```

This is how I'm fetchin the data:

```
func fetchRequestInfo() -> [MyData] {

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<GlucoseEvents> = GlucoseEvents.fetchRequest()

        do {
            let searchResults = try DatabaseController.getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)

            for result in searchResults as [GlucoseEvents] {
               let value = Int(result.value)
               let date = result.date as Date
               let take = Int(result.take)
               let commnt = String(describing: result.commnt)
                let data = MyData(value: value, date: date, take: take, commnt: commnt)
               self.dataArray.append(data)
                }



            } catch {

                print ("error: \(error)")

            }
        let orderArray = self.dataArray.sorted(by: { $0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedAscending})
        return orderArray
    }
```

And this is the how I set the properties of my CoreDataClass:

```
@NSManaged public var commnt: String?
    @NSManaged public var date: NSDate?
    @NSManaged public var value: Int16
    @NSManaged public var take: Int16
```

Comment: My guess: You have an *optional* NSDate.

Comment: How is `GlucoseEvents` defined? In particular the `fec` property?

Comment: @MartinR Sorry I eddited with the definition of GlucoseEvents, (and updated the varaible name to date)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`result.date` is an *optional* `NSDate`, so you can bridge it
to an optional `Date`:

```
result.date as Date?
```

Then use optional binding to safely unwrap it. In your case that
could be

```
guard let date = result.date as Date? else {
    // date is nil, ignore this entry:
    continue
}
```

You might also want to replace

```
let commnt = String(describing: result.commnt)
```

with

```
guard let commnt = result.commnt else {
    // commnt is nil, ignore this entry:
    continue
}
```

otherwise you'll get comment strings like `Optional(My comment)`.

(*Rule of thumb:* `String(describing: ...)` is almost never what you
want, even if the compiler suggests it to make the code compile.)

Answer (score 8):

Just make implicit casting like:

```
let nsdate = NSDate() 
let date = nsdate as Date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function or just an extension:

```
let nsDate = NSDate() 
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: nsDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
```